# Paypal mobile styling

Tags: mobile, paypal

I've a mobile version of my site which has a 'Donate via Paypal button' on it which is working fine. It's a button generated from within the paypal account that when clicked brings users to my account and asks them to enter an amount to donate and then either login or pay with CC.

Problem is the Paypal page it brings me to is not mobile optimised. From reading online It appears Paypal only offer the mobile enhanced version if you're using Paypal Mobile express checkout which is far more involved than simply adding a link onto your page.

The system I have now is 100% functional and does everything I want it to, I just want it to switch to the mobile version when you go to Paypal, to be honest it's very surprising Paypal doesn't do this automatically. They should detect a mobile browser and just change the stylesheet or redirect to the mobile-login page.

Is there any way of getting the mobile-styled paypal page without having to jump through the hoops of using the express payment system? I know it's not masively difficult but it is when compared to the really simple version I'm currently using.

Answer (score 2):

After hours messing with Pain Pal I finally figured out the issue. If you use a link generated by PP for donating ON THEIR SITE - ie. You go to Paypal and once there you enter the amount you wish to donate - the it won't style as the mobile site.

However, if you take the amount in on your own site and pass it to Paypal then it will auto change to the mobile site.

Ignore anyone on line (and there are plenty of people who do) telling you that to get the mobile styled site you need to use their mobile express checkout. You do not. At least not in the above scenario.

Comment: I am having the same problem as you. `What did you mean by pass it to PayPal?` Normally, one uses a html form with hidden fields and an image button.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant (although this was years ago so my recall isn't 100%). You get the user to enter the amount on your site and send that to Paypal. Using that system I arrived at the mobile site, otherwise I did not.

Comment: I am doing the same except that I have a Subscribe button, and may be you had a Buy button. I get a screen that looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555579/how-to-enable-mobile-paypal-payments-standard-on-sandbox.

Comment: Does a subscription always cost the same amount? If so can you hard code that amount into the paypal link? I believe that is what made it work for me.

Comment: Yes, subscription costs the same amount each month till it's canceled. I have a hidden field named `a3` in my page that I am setting to the amount based on subscription selected by user. I also tried a page where the hidden field `a3` had it's value already set, but it did not help.

Comment: And if you add the amount directly into the link that the button goes to when clicked? I think the parameter is something like _amnt or something like that. If you do that does the link become mobile friendly? By the way, this was 4 years ago and I don't have the code any more so Paypal might have changed how this works....but it's worth trying.

Comment: For subscriptions, amount is always specified by using `a3` hidden field. May be things have changed since the time you tried this.

Comment: I found the problem. When I use a standard Buy button which you probably used, then PayPal shows mobile optimized pages, BUT with Subscribe button, PayPal does NOT show mobile optimized pages. I tried a Buy button from PayPal and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard) the mobile optimisation is not working for "Donate" buttons.

Which command did you use ? 
With cmd=_donations its not showing the mobile version. When you use cmd=_xclick its mobile optimised, but then its not a "Donation" Site.