# How to enable Mobile PayPal Payments Standard on sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal Standard in sandbox environment for subscriptions. But, when I try to go through the payment screens after clicking on Subscribe button, I find that the PayPal pages are not optimized for mobile screens. So, I decided to enable `Mobile PayPal Payments Standard`, but cannot find a way to do so in sandbox environment.

**Question** : How to enable `Mobile PayPal Payments Standard` in sandbox environment? I logged into Paypal with the seller account and tried to find some option under Profile tab but could not find anything to turn this feature on.

Below is a screen shot of how PayPal login page looks on iPhone 6, which clearly is not optimized for mobile.

[image: Pay Pal Login on iPhone]

Also, when I went to following URL: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-standard, I found that pages are mobile-optimized but actually they are not as I tested on my mobile device. So, I think PayPal is confusing readers or giving wrong information or there is something missing in their docs.  You can see a screen shot below where PayPal confirms mobile-friendly pages.

[image: PayPal MisInformation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merchants that are integrated with the “Donate”, “Add to Cart”, or “Subscribe” buttons will not benefit from the mobile optimized experience at all at this time. Their customers will continue to go through the current payment experience on mobile devices.

Refer this link for more information about the Mobile PayPal payment Standard: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/

Comment: I am using Subscribe button on my website. I guess there is no other option other than to use a different provider other than PayPal if mobile friendliness is a requirement.

Comment: @sunil: You can try the PayPal Express checkout Recurring Payment solution which is API based and need coding knowledge. Refer the following for REST API : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans